# Confusing arrays

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Kinda new to iOS, Im also studying Android. kinda confuse on arrays.

How to convert this into iOS:

`result` as being the index

`nextresult[x]` array of indexes

```
for(x = 0; x < array.size; x++)
{
   if(result < nextresult[x])
         nextresult[x] -= 1; 
}
```

It will iccheck all of the content of the arrays if it needs to be adjusted or not,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be following will give you some idea -
As you mentioned, i have considered following - `result' is value and`nextresult` is array.

```
for(x = 0; x < [array count]; x++)
{
   if(result < [nextresult objectAtIndex:x]) {
       [nextresult objectAtIndex:x] -= 1; 
    }
}
```

EDIT - 
if you want to add integer in arrays -

```
[yourArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]; // Objective C array store objects. so we need to convert primitive data type into object.
```

Comment: how to have an NSMutableArray based on button.tag, that is save in like this:     NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"Key"];

Answer (score 2):

Read Apple's excellent developer documentation.

You can find the docs about the NSArray class [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), or in your Xcode organizer.

I have downvoted your question, because it could very easily have been solved by just looking at the docs.